# Checking for HTML5 File API Support in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, html5-filesystem

When coding a check for HTML5 File API browser support like this:

```
  private hasHtml5FileApiSupport;
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(DOCUMENT) document: Document) {
    const w = document.defaultView;
    this.hasHtml5FileApiSupport = w.File && w.FileReader && w.FileList && w.Blob;
```

VSCode draws red squigglies under the `w.File && w.FileReader && w.FileList` parts.

Is there a way to get rid of these / Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we inject `document` using the `Document` type then we get the strict type checking, and VSCode draws squigglies, however if we use `any` instead of `Document` the errors disappear:

```
private hasHtml5FileApiSupport;
constructor(@Optional() @Inject(DOCUMENT) document: any) {
  const w = document.defaultView;
  this.hasHtml5FileApiSupport = w.File && w.FileReader && w.FileList && w.Blob;
}
```