# Typescript HTML5 API Typings

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, html5-filesystem

Anyone know if there exists type definitions for the HTML5 File API?  Specifically:

- FileList
- File
- Blob
- FileReader

Also in Angular there is a `document.defaultView` object that represents the window, but it does not the full Window interface with respect to the Html5 File API, so it would be necessary to cast `document.defaultView` to an instance that has the `Window` interface for the file API.

Comment: They should be a part of the standard DOM type library [`lib.dom.d.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts).

Comment: Does not look like the `Window` interface has `File` and `FileReader` properties on it, which probably explains why Typescript complains when we attempt to use that namespace in  Angular.

Comment: You could potentially use declaration merging to attach `File` and `FileReader` to the `Window` interface.

Comment: So if we try to do this: `    const w = document.defaultView;
` and ` this.hasHtml5FileApiSupport = w.File && w.FileReader && w.FileList && w.Blob;
` the VSCode draws red squigglies under the properties that are not defined on the `Window` interface.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger I could extend the `Window` interface with a custom interface also ... but I'm wondering why the properties are not on the `Window` interface.  They could be null, but at least if they are defined, it makes the code a bit more DRY ... Perhaps I should put it in as a feature request?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell you why `File` and `FileReader` are not included on the `Window` object already. You can certainly open an issue with `typescript` to see if they plan on adding them. In the meantime, the easiest way to "patch" this oversight would be to use declaration merging.

Window.d.ts

```
interface Window {
    File?:File;
    FileReader?:FileReader;
}
```

Now `File` and `FileReader` will be available on the `Window` object anywhere in your project.

Comment: I added another related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53292312/checking-for-html5-file-api-support-in-angular